# Why does Twilio Connect App not redirect me back with the Authorize URL, but just sends me to the Twilio console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio, twilio-api

I am having problems with Twilio connect app. 
After clicking on the link generated on Twilio connect app panel, 
logging twice and redirected to my projects inside Twilio.
It was supposed that after selecting one of the projects it should redirect me back with the Authorize URL, but it just sends me to the Twilio console. 
Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have this problem too. I have been told by Twilio support that it is being fixed. However 2 weeks have gone by and still no fix or update.

If you create a new account, it works.
If you go to log in with an existing account, it just redirects to Twilio not back to your app.

Comment: They did fix it eventually. But it took them 2+ months and and that point I moved on. I don't think it's a feature they really care about.